# How to make Firebase SDK working on visionOS simulator?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, visionos

My app is broken with bunch of errors on Vision Pro simulator coming from Firebase SDK. Has anyone managed to make it working? I am using "open --env FIREBASE_SOURCE_FIRESTORE /path/to/project.xcodeproj" command, but does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase 10.18.0, due out later this week should address Firestore build issues with Xcode 15.1.

The availability options for visionOS are changing in almost every Xcode release so Firebase has needed several updates since the initial Xcode 15 beta. Details in the Firebase visionOS [GitHub issues](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20%20label%3AvisionOS%20).